# htaccess - Redirects don't work or produce conflicts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having an issue where some of the redirects don't work without a `/` at the end of the URL. Additionally, sometimes I have conflicting redirects that rewrite the following redirect.

#### Global Rules

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

#### Doesn't work without slashes

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)launch/$ /$1products/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)solutions/$ /$1products/ [R=301,L]
```

*Example:*
When I search for `/launch` without the last `/` then I end up at my 404 page.

#### Conflicts for second and third

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)products/overview/heartbeat/$ /$1products/heartbeat/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)heartbeat/$ /$1products/heartbeat/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)heartbeat-beta/$ /$1products/heartbeat-beta/ [R=301,L]
```

*Example:*
When I search for `/heartbeat-beta/` and expect to get `/products/heartbeat-beta/` my result is:
`/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/heartbeat-beta/`

Comment: Concretize with some examples of input URLs and what happens, or how it misbehaves. Trailing slashes can be made optional with `?` just like in the catch-all rule from the first example.

Comment: @mario I've updated the post with examples for the two situations. Sorry I'm a newb when it comes this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules are not in correct order have some suspicious regex patterns. Have it in this order:

```
RewriteRule ^(heartbeat(?:-beta)?)/?$ /products/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^products/overview/(heartbeat)/?$ /products/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

**PS:** To make trailing slash optional use `/?$` in your regex pattern.

Comment: A lot of what I've done is copied from the original author. I'll make these changes elsewhere. What does the `:`, `L` and  `NC` if you don't mind answering. Or direct me to some good reading.

Comment: `L` is for `Last` and `NC` is for `ignore case`. For a tutorial I would suggest: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708